# Slack SDK for Python client.api_call method arguments syntax

Tags: python, sdk, slack, slack-api

I'm trying to create a python script that reads all messages from a channel (e.g. [Retrieving conversation history](https://api.slack.com/messaging/retrieving#conversations)). However, there is no implementation of that directly in this SDK. Closest thing is listing all channels.

There is a way to call any api method using [this](https://slack.dev/python-slackclient/basic_usage.html#calling-any-api-methods) general form (also shown below). I cannot figure out the syntax for passing arguments with the "conversations.history" method found [here](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history). My current try is at the bottom.

```
response = client.api_call(
  api_method='chat.postMessage',
  json={'channel': '#random','text': "Hello world!"}
)

##########

response = client.api_call(
  api_method='conversations.history',
  token=slack_token,
  channel="C0XXXXXXXXX"
)
```

[This](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient/search?q=api_call) search on the GitHub may also help for those inclined.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pulling historical channel messages python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56744339/pulling-historical-channel-messages-python)

Comment: Yes! Thank you @JaiPandya. I figured the answer was out there somewhere I just could not find it with what I was searching. I also dug into the docs more and found https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient/blob/c758d7f03667e711f7403060fa4002418fd031fb/slack/web/base_client.py#L72 really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method:

```
client.conversations_history(
    channel=CHANNEL,
    limit=MESSAGES_PER_PAGE,
)
```

This is explained in another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56755815/410367).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem is their example doesn't include any params, just the json body of a POST message which might give the reader the impression that all params go into `json=`.

What you need is:

```
response = client.api_call(
  api_method='conversations.history',
  params={'token': slack_token,
          'channel': "C0XXXXXXXXX"}
)
```

You need to pass post body as `json=` and query params as `params=`
I received the following error:

```
The request to the Slack API failed. (url: https://www.slack.com/api/conversations.members)
The server responded with: {'ok': False, 'error': 'invalid_arguments', 'response_metadata': {'messages': ['[ERROR] missing required field: channel']}}
```

Here is a definition of api_call in base_client.py
https://github.com/slackapi/python-slack-sdk/blob/6ab8bd2fcdcabb55e722ee520e6946c5b0b43f1d/slack_sdk/web/base_client.py#L93